# Running Seq from the command line results in a HttpSysException "Access is denied"

Tags: asp.net-core, seq-logging, httpsys

When I try to run [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) from a regular command line as a normal user

`seq run --nologo --listen="http://localhost:5435/" --storage="C:\\temp\\Seq"`

I get the following exception

```
Running as server; press Ctrl+C to exit.

[23:36:16 INF] Seq "5.1.3364" running on OS "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro"
[23:36:17 ERR] Start
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException (5): Access is denied
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlGroup.RegisterPrefix(String uriPrefix, Int32 contextId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlPrefixCollection.RegisterAllPrefixes(UrlGroup urlGroup)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener.Start()
[23:36:17 FTL] Error running the server application
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException (5): Access is denied
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlGroup.RegisterPrefix(String uriPrefix, Int32 contextId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlPrefixCollection.RegisterAllPrefixes(UrlGroup urlGroup)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
   at Seq.Server.ServiceProcess.ServerService.Start()
```

Doing the same thing as admin works just fine but after add the URL using

`netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:5435/ user=MyDomain\MyUser`

when I run Seq, I get a different exeception:

```
Running as server; press Ctrl+C to exit.

[23:19:43 INF] Seq "5.1.3364" running on OS "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro"
[23:19:44 ERR] Start
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException (183): The prefix 'http://+:5435/' is already registered.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlGroup.RegisterPrefix(String uriPrefix, Int32 contextId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlPrefixCollection.RegisterAllPrefixes(UrlGroup urlGroup)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener.Start()
[23:19:44 FTL] Error running the server application
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException (183): The prefix 'http://+:5435/' is already registered.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlGroup.RegisterPrefix(String uriPrefix, Int32 contextId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlPrefixCollection.RegisterAllPrefixes(UrlGroup urlGroup)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
   at Seq.Server.ServiceProcess.ServerService.Start()
```

How can I run Seq from the command line as regular user on a machine that is in a domain?